# How can i toggle html element visibility with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a map (made of svg elements) which looks like the following at startup.

[image]

When a user clicks a 'zone' i would like for two things to happen. Only one zone can be clicked at at time.

1. The zone receives an 'active' class tag so the style changes to represent a selected state.
2. The markers for that zone become visible.

[image]

Then a user can click a 'marker' in that zone which gets the following 'active' tag applied so it appears selected to the user as well. Only one marker can be selected at a time as well.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style type="text/css">
  * {
    background: rgb(40,40,40);
  }
  .zone {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    stroke-width: 1;
    cursor: hand;
  }
  .marker {
    fill: rgba(255,0,0,1.0);
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke-width: 0;
    cursor: crosshair;
  }
  .active_zone {
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    fill: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .active_marker {
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke-width: 1;
  }
</style>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg width="500px" viewBox="0 0 374 180" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
        
        <!-- Zones -->
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" d="M90,37L47,106L91,176L159,179L176,125L220,91L180,44L90,37Z"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" d="M250,21L318.436,37L333,116L285,201L159,179L176,125L220,91L180,44L250,21Z"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" d="M416,56L318.436,37L333,116L285,201L421,183L409,120L416,56Z"/>
        </g>

        <!-- Markers -->
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <rect class="marker active_marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,106,-29.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,30,-2.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,132,60.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,195,84)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,204,-11.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,230,33)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-21,15.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,79,69.5)">
            <rect class="marker" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the JavaScript that you have tried.  If you don't have any, consider reviewing: [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the answer to this was fun, I've never worked with SVG's.

jQuery cannot apply `.addClass()` to path elements, so in my original answer nothing was working - I was clicking but there were no style changes. The solution to this was using `.attr()`, which is why you see that in the answer. I added a class, `.marker-visible` so that I can 1) distinguish which markers are shown and 2) actually show the markers. Every zone and marker has a `data-zone` attribute that tells the javascript which zone is being clicked and which markers are part of that zone.

I created a click handler for the zones in `document.ready()`, and all that click handler does is reset the class on all zones (so they appear unclicked) and adds the `zone-active` class to the clicked zone. Then it shows all the markers in the zone by finding all markers that have the same `data-zone` tag.

I used `$(document).on('click', '.marker-visible')` rather than `$('.marker-visible').click()` because the markers get the `marker-visible` class assigned *on the fly*, so I can't assign the click handler on the fly as well (I could but that wouldn't be the best). Instead, I assigned it to the document so it always runs and I don't need to assign and drop click handlers during runtime. The click handler does practically the same thing as the zone click handler, in that it just resets the classes of all the other visible markers and gives the clicked marker the `marker-active` class.

Comment if you need any further clarification.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.zone').click(function(){
    $('.zone').attr('class', 'zone');
    $('.marker').attr('class', 'marker');
    $(this).attr('class', 'zone zone-active');
    $('.marker[data-zone="' + $(this).data('zone') + '"]').attr('class', 'marker marker-visible');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.marker-visible', function(){
    $('.marker-visible').attr('class', 'marker marker-visible');
    $(this).attr('class', 'marker marker-visible marker-active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style type="text/css">
  * {
    background: rgb(40,40,40);
  }
  .zone {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    stroke-width: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .marker {
    fill: rgba(255,0,0,1.0);
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke-width: 0;
    cursor: crosshair;
    display: none;
  }
  .zone-active {
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    fill: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .marker-visible{
    display: block;
  }
  .marker-active {
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke-width: 1;
  }
</style>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg width="500px" viewBox="0 0 374 180" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
        
        <!-- Zones -->
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" data-zone="1" d="M90,37L47,106L91,176L159,179L176,125L220,91L180,44L90,37Z"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" data-zone="2" d="M250,21L318.436,37L333,116L285,201L159,179L176,125L220,91L180,44L250,21Z"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <path class="zone" data-zone="3" d="M416,56L318.436,37L333,116L285,201L421,183L409,120L416,56Z"/>
        </g>

        <!-- Markers -->
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-47,-21)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="1" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,106,-29.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="2" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,30,-2.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="1" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,132,60.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="2" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,195,84)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="3" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,204,-11.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="3" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,230,33)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="3" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-21,15.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="1" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,79,69.5)">
            <rect class="marker" data-zone="2" x="94" y="56" width="18" height="18"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, you beat me to it, i came back to post my js code as i had made some progress but i was no where close what you had. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: It's why I created a Stack Overflow account ;)

Comment: I scanned over your code and you developed it in a very clean and understanding way that is easy to read as well. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery have a Toggle function** to solve your problem:

```
.toggle()
```

I hope it's helps ;)